# Initial Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, moderators

GenAI Stack Exchange is just over seven weeks old, during this time, it's been moderated by community managers. The reason for this is because of its unique origin as an experiment for a possible site creation process, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood?cb=1).

We wanted to check in with the community to see if there was any interest in holding an election to add moderators. The main reason is to add individuals with greater expertise than the CMs to help with moderation. In addition, we also don't want this site to go to long as a CM-moderated site. Elected moderators would still be expected to work with the stakeholder group on policy, site changes, and general site business, as has been the norm for this site since its creation. CM support would still otherwise remain the same as it has been.

This doesn't change the nature of this site still being an experiment, and isn't Stack Overflow the company considering it to be a success or complete.

### What does it take to be a Moderator?

Prior to 2018, [moderators were handpicked by staff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), and referred to as pro-tempore or pro-tem mods, because they were intended to serve only until the community could run its own elections. The Community Management team would look for users who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- Have an eye for content that should be flagged, closed, or removed, and act on that within the expectations of the community and Stack Exchange generally

### Electing your moderators

In 2018, however, beta sites began electing their own pro-tem moderators, joining community-elected moderators on network sites that have left their beta phase. The process is mostly the same, but if you’re interested in the full details, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). If you are interested in nominating yourself, you are invited to state your intention to do so in an answer here. Additionally, if you feel someone would be a good fit as a moderator on this site, feel free to use an answer to this question to support them and encourage them to run.

### NOTES:

- **This is not an official election nomination thread.** It’s just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination here.
- **In order to be considered as a candidate**, applicants must comply with the requirements listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work/135361#135361), specifically:

  - Have at least 300 reputation.
  - Be "in good standing", i.e. not have been [suspended on any site in the past year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).
  - Be [18 years of age or older](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357378/355458), or be 18 years of age or older by the end of the election.

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: IMO, there is currently very low participation in the community. Too low to have a proper election.

Comment: Not a good time for me personally; I'm moving house (again).

Comment: As the pro-tempore-moderators will join Stakeholders to discuss site policies, etc., , should we promote this post among non-Stakeholders in some way? I don't remember having seen a featured meta post in the community digest.

Comment: How will people who don't regularly visit Meta know they were nominated by someone else? Will the CM team send a private message to them?

Comment: @Wicket Not sure I follow this; it is being promoted on the GenAI site via the featured tag. Also, the nominating of people to be mods is common practice for interest checks on sites that are in private beta so borrowed that language for this.

Comment: The *Community Bulletin* is shown on the site, it shows the featured meta posts from the site, from Meta Stack Exchange, and the company blog. The *Community Digest* is a newsletter that is sent by email. I think that I got subscribed automatically.  All SE Community Digests are listed at https://stackexchange.com/digests, and there are subcribe and preview links for each Community Digest. Since https://stackexchange.com looks not to be touched in a long time, I don't know if the preview shows what is being sent.

Comment: The Community Bulletin might work with people who regularly visit the site. The Community Digest, might work with people that not visit the site, but follow what happens throw by the email newsletter. What if someone that is nominated have not visited the site since they where nominated? Does the protocol consider to reach them someway, let say to accept the nomination / confirm to be interested on participate?

Comment: Talking about promoting this post, I jumped into the [Prompt Design Stakeholders chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1717/prompt-design-stakeholders), which is hosted in Meta Stack Exchange. Fortunately, Journeyman unfrozen it a few moments before so I could post a link to this post. I also added a link to the [GenAI chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147284/genai). Could be a good idea to bump **one** of the existing Meta Stack Exchange posts about the Prompt Design proposal / GenAI Site making an update to include a link to this post?

Comment: This community is not ready. Actually, it should start from Area51, just like ***every single site on the network***.

Comment: I'm not particularly in favour of authoritarian appointments ([cough cough](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/131/278)), but @Nike's point is exactly why we used to do that. This community is not large enough to hold a proper election. (Though, Area 51 isn't _exactly_ as necessary as all that, and may not have helped here.)

Comment: @Nike That was already discussed / answered in [Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463/1359324). The proper place to "bump" such discussion is Meta SE. Still, it makes sense that you share here your opinion on how the lack of the Area 51 proposal affects this "Community Interest Check".

Comment: @Wicket just because it has been "discussed" doesn't make what happened here okay.